# Firefox application sound resetting itself to50%

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

since a few days I have the following problem in Ubuntu 16.04: 
The application volume (as shown in `Sound settings > applications`) of Firefox resets itself to about 50% any time an audio stream ends. I can set it to 100%, but as soon as the current audio (e.g. a video) ends it is automatically reset.

No other application is affected.

I've tried deleting `~/.config/pulse`, as suggested [in a simlar thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786957/sound-resets-to-100-after-reboot-on-ubuntu-16-04) which hasn't helped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox starts in mute by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908262/firefox-starts-in-mute-by-default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908262/firefox-starts-in-mute-by-default?rq=1).

In Firefox's `about:config`change `media.default_volume` value to `10`