# Volume sometimes goes to maximum

Tags: sound, 17.10, volume-control, media-buttons

If I turn up the volume on Ubuntu 17.10, it sometimes continues to the maximum. Given that I only pressed the button once, it should theoretically increment the volume only by one step. Note that I am only aware of the problem happening with volume control buttons, and not any other method of adjusting the volume since I never use those.

How can I fix that?

**EDIT**

System specs

```
$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: ie31200_edac

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: f6000000-f70fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000f1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at f7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at f7a14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
    Memory at f7a00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at f7a1e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f7a1c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at f7a10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f7900000-f79fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: f7800000-f78fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f2100000-00000000f21fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f7a1b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer HM86 Express LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at f7a1a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at f7a19000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer GM108M [GeForce 840M]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [disabled] [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev c3)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at f7900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
    Memory at f7800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci

04:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Memory at f2104000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f2100000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: It could be a hardware related issue, could you add more info about hardware  (like brand/model)? Also try solutions here https://askubuntu.com/q/786957/26246

Comment: I've noticed that it only happens when I'm using my headphones.

Comment: So I've tried deleting the contents of `~/.config/pulse/` and rebooting because I had upgraded from 16.04, as suggested by @user.dz's link, but the issue still persists.

Comment: @Fabby Thanks, will try that. Since you're saying that it's a hardware problem, is there any particular reason why I've never had this issue when I boot into Windows?

Comment: I don't think it's a hardware issue. I've got the issue on a brand-new laptop - which doesn't do it in other distributions of linux.

Comment: Understood! Comment and question upvoted and original comment removed. **:-)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research and your problem might be that your volume buttons change the volume by more than they are supposed to, maybe by 100% instead of 5%. Try changing your settings as pictured in this gif:

[image: change command run from volume key press]

The gif is from this post here:

[How do I set a custom keyboard shortcut to control volume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181341/how-do-i-set-a-custom-keyboard-shortcut-to-control-volume)

which talks about changing the command executed when you press the volume buttons.

If that doesn't work you can go the crude route and add a command launcher to your tool bar with some icons. I made this gif to show you what I mean:

[image: adding a volume button to your toolbar]

commands:

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+
amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-
```

I am running Ubuntu MATE in the gif which has some slight differences from normal Ubuntu but they should still work about the same way, hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for the edit stumblebee, I'm still new so I don't have enough rep for inline images.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just had a chance to test it, and it looks like it works well! I don't get a notification when I change the volume, but that's nothing a bash script with a few clever `notify-send`s shouldn't fix.

Comment: If anyone else is having the problem that the commands are setting the volume to 0, reference [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181341/how-do-i-set-a-custom-keyboard-shortcut-to-control-volume#comment1482733_591605), based on the above link.